# Error al insertar: entrada duplicada '0' para clave primaria

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla persona en mi base de datos, que defino de la siguiente manera:

```
CREATE TABLE `persona` (
 `documento` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `nombres` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `apellidos` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `telefono` varchar(23) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `direccion` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `username` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`documento`),
 KEY `username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Y cuando intento hacer un `insert` como éste:

```
INSERT INTO `persona` (`documento`, `nombres`, `apellidos`, `telefono`, `direccion`, `username`) 
VALUES ('88668', 'theth', 'thetn', '2256', 'thrther', 'juancho')
```

Me aparece el siguiente mensaje de error:

> Error #1062 - Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

¿Por qué ocurre eso y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: El error se te produce por que tu llave se te esta duplicando. si estas usando un entero fíjate que tenga declarado el auto incrementado.si la estas generando fíjate que no se repita.

Comment: 1088348, este de momento es el unico id que tenemos, asi que no lo estamos duplicando, nosotros si generamos el id pero no lo duplicamos

Comment: pues por que tienes el campo documento como primary key y no te va a permitir duplicar valores que tienen ese atributo

Comment: Lee [ask]. El primer consejo que encontrarás allí es "busca e investiga". [Esta misma pregunta ya se ha hecho en el sitio varias veces](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Duplicate+entry+%270%27+for+key+%27PRIMARY%27) y puedes encontrar respuestas que te serán de utilidad (no será tu código exactamente, pero la idea del problema/solución será la misma).

Comment: @JUANCAMILORUIZRAMIREZ Así como está planteada la pregunta, el error no se puede reproducir. ¿Estás usando algún lenguaje para hacer el `INSERT`? Me inclino a pensar que si, y que el problema debe estar en ese otro código.

Answer (score 3):

si es un bigint no debe llevar comillas:

```
INSERT INTO `persona` 
       (`documento`, `nombres`, `apellidos`, `telefono`,  `direccion`, `username`) 
VALUES (      88668,   'theth',     'thetn',     '2256',    'thrther', 'juancho' )
```

Answer (score 1):

Cuando tengas campos numéricos (que no campos de texto en los que guardes numeros) en la BBDD no los pases valores a estos en la consulta entre comillas, pásalos directamente sin estas.

Es decir, en lugar de ('1', 'asdf', '2', 'qwerty') usa este formato: (1, 'asdf', 2, 'qwerty').

Por mi experiencia te diría que es por esto por lo que te esta fallando, y si no es por esto, es probable que también tengas este fallo si no lo cambias.

Answer (score 0):

si este numero ya existe 88668 te dará error.

puede resolverlo con agregar el auto incremento al primary key o recrear la tabla de la siguiente forma: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12189846/4717133

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer el consecutivo de tu tabla (autoincrement) está desactualizado.
Lista la tabla que te está generando el problema y revisa el índice auto increment. Si no está bien configurado, usar

```
ALTER TABLE nombre_tabla AUTO_INCREMENT = siguiente_numero; 
FLUSH TABLE nombre_tabla;
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).